# Transform CRS for all geometry objects in SQL-Database in one step

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

I would like to easily change the CRS for **all** my geometry objects in a PostGIS/SpaitaLite/GPKG database in *one step*. In my case, all objects are in EPSG:4326 and I want them in EPSG:3044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GeoPackage and SpatiaLite that is easy, just create a new database with ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg -t_srs epsg:3044 converted.gpkg source.gpkg

ogr2ogr -f sqlite -dsco spatialite=yes -t_srs epsg:3044 converted.sqlite source.sqlite
```

Same approach should work also for PostGIS but you must create a new database with PostgreSQL tools first because GDAL can't do that.

All other options I was thinking about would require some scripting and can't perhaps be classified as true one step solutions.